# Facebook-api, ошибка 101 при вызове метода page.isFan

Tags: facebook, facebook-api

Здравствуйте! Есть страница, на которой находится приложение и размещена кнопка `like`. Я хочу проверить, нажимал ли пользователь на эту кнопку. Для этого пишу:

```
FB.api({ method: 'pages.isFan', page_id: '276906669071860', uid: flashVars[userIdKey]}, function(resp) {
if (resp == true)
{
alert("like");
} else 
    alert("not " + resp.error_code + " " + resp.error_msg);
});
```

Но постоянно получаю ошибку 101 - `invalid appliction id`. Причем тут `application id` - не понимаю. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Если попробовать использовать `/USER_ID/likes/PAGE_ID` : 
`FB.api('/100004473481322/likes/276906669071860',function(response)` ....
то `response.data - undefined`

Answer (score 1):

```
Есть страница, на которой находится приложение и размещена кнопка like
```

Значит есть приложение!

```
Но постоянно получаю ошибку 101 - invalid appliction id. Причем тут application id - не понимаю.
```

Ну значит нужно вставить этот **application id** в метод, и ошибка, как по взмаху волшебной палочки, исчезнет :)

Comment: а page_id и application_id могут совпадать?

Comment: вряд ли, хотя все возможно. Но это не тот вопрос который должен был возникнуть с твоей стороны.

Comment: Теперь 104 - incorrect signature

Comment: >incorrect signature

значит неправильно она формируется.